# Prevent autofill the saved password in angular material design

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

How to prevent the password field from auto-fill with saved password in angular material design

I have used autocomplete="off" it does not worked for me.

```html
   <md-input-container class="md-block margin-top-10" flex-gt-sm>

      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="auth.user.password"  
         name="password" ng-required="true" autocomplete="off" >  
      </md-input-container>
```

Comment: There a few questions about this including this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is an issue for material, as documented [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1849).

As mentioned in the comments there is a workaround for this just add `autocomplete="off"` in the form definition.

Comment: add autocomplete="off" in the form definition  does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="new-password"` this is working for me.to avoid auto saved passwords and as well as auto fill.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).